# Enabling OpenGL Core Profile in QT4 on OS X

Tags: macos, qt, opengl, osx-lion

I just upgraded to Lion and am trying to get some practice coding with GLSL 1.50, however I can't get my code to run above OpenGL 2.1 thus I get "version '150' is not supported" errors when trying to compile my shaders.

The set up is as follows:
I am using 2 x 2.8Ghz Quad-Core Xeons with a GeForce 8800GT in OS X 10.7.2 and using QT creator 2.3 & QT version 4.7.
To set up my OpenGL context I use a class derived from QGLWidget.
As I plan to have a second QGLWidget with a similar setup, my aim has been to change the default format for my QGLWidget(s) like so:

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);

QGLFormat f;
f.setVersion(3, 2);
f.setProfile(QGLFormat::CoreProfile);
QGLFormat::setDefaultFormat(f);

GUIVolumePanel* pvp = new GUIVolumePanel(prc, x, y, z);
std::tr1::shared_ptr<GUIMainWindow> prog(new GUIMainWindow(pvp));
```

However this appears to have no effect on my OpenGL context and I am at a loss as to figure out why.

Comment: It's possible that QT hasn't been updated yet with the new context creation for OSX 10.7.

Answer (score 0):

I Googled it and found

http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewthread/8047

which leads me to think 4.7 does not support it directly yet. There is some code posted there that might get you going as a work around. You might also try qt 4.8 rc.

Given that Lion came out after qt 4.7 was out I would not expect it to work right off.